# Buffer 100m for all the points in the table with 50M entries in Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis, coordinate-transformation

I have a table with 50M entries with its latitude and longitude, the geom is created as I imported from QGIS. I am trying to create a buffer of 100m for all the points in the table by calling the table in jupyter notebook. I have also tried to convert the coordinate system using SRID:25832 for the buffer in meters but I cannot see the points projected to the right place in postgresql view.

```
SELECT * FROM public."operation"
ST_Buffer(geom, 100, 25832)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the geometries are encoded in a lon/lat spatial reference system you just need to cast it to `geography` and apply the buffer function. Using `geography` it the unit used is metre:

```
-- buffer of 100 metres
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom::geography,100) FROM public.operation;
```

Or if you wish to use EPSG:25832 you have to transform it first

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(geom,25832),100) FROM public.operation;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a7b70256048abbc2f2ae4e5569519b7)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  If I transform the coordinates the points are not in the same position, it moves to infinity and the base map is not visible.  If I use this    'SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(geom,25832),100) FROM public.operation;' second operation.

Comment: @Aravinth which SRID are you transforming from?

Comment: the data is in wgs 84 SRID:4326

Comment: @Aravinth so I suggest you to use `::geography` (first query), it will create the buffers using metres. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried the first query, it works fine. My other data are in SRIDD: 25832, if I need to do some operations with those shapefiles what can be done if it not transformed.

Comment: @Aravinth in that case you don't have to transform at all, just create the buffer in the unit of epsg 25832, which already is metre.

Comment: how to add the buffer result as a new column to the existing table "Operation".

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: Please, that will be helpful